# HighCharts missing data points on line chart

Tags: javascript, highcharts, points

I'm using highcharts to plot data and on some data series there are no data points like on image bellow and the jsFiddle example. Before I log a issue on github I want to ask you if there are something that I miss or it id really an issue.

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Javascript

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
                type: 'line',
                animation: false
            },
            title: {
                text: "abc"
            },
            xAxis: {
                type: 'datetime',
                dateTimeLabelFormats: { // don't display the dummy year
                    month: '%e. %b',
                    year: '%b'
                }
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Time [ms]'

                },
                labels: {
                    step: 1
                },
                tickInterval: 100,
                minRange: 400
                //range: 200
            },
            plotOptions: {
                line: {
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true,
                        allowOverlap: true,
                        borderWidth: 2,
                        style: {
                            textShadow: false
                        },
                        padding: 2.5
                    },
                    //selected: true,
                    enableMouseTracking: true,
                    animation: false,
                    allowPointSelect: true,
                    /*stacking: 'percent'*/
                },

            },
        series: [{
        "name": "a",
        "data": [[1458604800000, 1800], [1458691200000, 1600], [1458777600000, 1800], [1458864000000, 1800], [1459123200000, 1800], [1459209600000, 1800]],
        "color": "rgba(91,155,213,1)",
        "dataLabels": {"color": "rgba(91,155,213,1)", "y": 0},
        "_symbolIndex": 0
    }, {
        "name": "b",
        "data": [[1458604800000, 1500], [1458691200000, 1500], [1458864000000, 1500], [1459123200000, 1500], [1459209600000, 1500]],
        "color": "rgba(165,165,165,1)",
        "dataLabels": {"color": "rgba(165,165,165,1)", "y": 24},
        "_symbolIndex": 1
    }, {
        "name": "c",
        "data": [[1458604800000, 1400], [1458691200000, 1300], [1458777600000, 1300], [1459123200000, 1100], [1459123200000, 1100], [1459209600000, 1100]],
        "color": "rgba(237,125,49,1)",
        "dataLabels": {"color": "rgba(237,125,49,1)", "y": 0},
        "_symbolIndex": 2
    }]
    });
});

var seriesToReproduce = [{"name":"a","data":[[1458604800000,1800],[1458691200000,1700],[1458777600000,1700],[1458864000000,1700],[1459123200000,1700],[1459209600000,1700]],"color":"rgba(237,125,49,1)","dataLabels":{"color":"rgba(237,125,49,1)","y":0},"_symbolIndex":0},{"name":"b","data":[[1458604800000,2100],[1458691200000,2000],[1458864000000,2100],[1459123200000,2000],[1459123200000,2000],[1459209600000,2000]],"color":"rgba(165,165,165,1)","dataLabels":{"color":"rgba(165,165,165,1)","y":24},"_symbolIndex":1},{"name":"c","data":[[1458604800000,2300],[1458691200000,2200],[1458777600000,2200],[1458864000000,2200],[1459123200000,2200],[1459209600000,2200]],"color":"rgba(91,155,213,1)","dataLabels":{"color":"rgba(91,155,213,1)","y":0},"_symbolIndex":2}]
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6qw7su3a/)

No data points screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NS8Rl.png

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You have to dig into the documentation for the `marker` attribute of `series` to find that there is an `enabled` property, and it says :

> **enabled: Boolean**
>
> Enable or disable the point marker. If null, the markers are hidden when the data is > dense, and shown for more widespread data points. Defaults to null.

So I don't know how they determine that the data is dense or not, but if you want the markers to be always displayed, you should set the `enabled` property to true.

Answer (score 3):

[updated Plunk](http://jsfiddle.net/6qw7su3a/1/)

In highcharts APi there is an option for enabling Markers [link](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#series<line>.marker),

use

```
plotOptions: {
        series: {
            marker: {
                enabled: true

            }
        }
    },
```

for enabling markers in your series ,